# SoapUI Xpath assertion: match the exact length of the field

Tags: xpath, soapui, assertion

I need to match, exact length of a string and I'm using below code for that :

```
declare namespace 
ns123='urn:lt:sb:xmlns:services:customers:customerinformationfile:GetCustByGlobalId:1.2';
matches(//ns123:legalCode, "[0-9-]{10}")
```

Problem is that it works only for greater length (for example, if field content is 11, it fails, but it doesn't, if the content is 9).

Comment: If you want to check string-length you should not use regex, just try build-in XPath method, e.g. `string-length(//ns123:legalCode)=10` (check that length is exactly 10 chars), `string-length(//ns123:legalCode)>10` (more than 10), etc...

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. You just need to set some start and end boundaries in your regex:

`^[0-9-]{10}$`